# Passing variable to css as title

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, css-selectors

I see that you can create "variables" inside css:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_var.asp

My files:

```
(style.css file)

[title~=--myVariable] {
    color: red
}
```

```
(App.js file)
...
return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 title="thisIsTheTitle"> Some text in red color ? </h1>
    </div>
  )
```

Is it possible to do so that if my header has a title, then the color is red
otherwise stays at is (black)

**UPDATE**
I forgot initialize myVariable, so:

```
(style.css file)

:root {
  --myVariable: white;
}
```

Comment: I don’t see any css custom properties in your code (the other name for css variables)

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not possible. CSS vars are used only withing CSS and cannot be injected from a JS code. Look at dynamic styling solutions, like [JSS](https://cssinjs.org/?v=v10.0.4) or [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/). They allow use JS to create styles in code.

Comment: I will have to use them finally, but if the upper isn't possible then it will not work...
(because i will pass them to react, but still -> now the title checks for string "myVariable" and i want the value of variable to be there.... l updated the question

Comment: @Fyodor the problem is i'm using external components (library?) in react, and there is no implementation of styling in some elements, so i'm trying to add it as shown above. So unfortunately your solution will not help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can set fallbacks with css var().

however please note:

> The var() function cannot be used in property names, selectors or anything else besides property values
>   [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var)

update: I saw you're edit, so as the quote above that will not work.

Comment: The problem is that my title is created dynamically. I don't know what it will be.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this part:

> Is it possible to do so that if my header has a title, then the color is red otherwise stays at is (black)

(style.css file)

```css
.App h1 {
    color: black;
}

.red {
    color: red;
}
```

(App.js file)

```js
...
function App({ headerTitle }) {
return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 title={ headerTitle }
     className={headerTitle ? 'red' : null } > 
        Some text in red color ? </h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```